# Passing id of selected dropdown option to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using mvc3 nhibernate and creating a search application...
Here i am creating a dropdown list containing all Hobby names and on click of search button the selected option's id should go to post method
i have written following code in my controller

```
public ActionResult Details()
{

ViewBag.h=new SelectList(new Hobby_MasterService().GetHobbies(),"Hobby_Id");

return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(int Hobby_Id)
{
Hobby_Master hm = new Hobby_MasterService().GetHobby_Data(Hobby_Id);
return RedirectToAction("Show");
}
```

and in view i'm only showing one drop down list as

```
<b>Select Hobby:</b>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Hobbies", FormMethod.Get))
{
 <div class="Editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Hobby_Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.h)

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

My dropdown is populated through a function which has a normal sql statement...
and i can generate list....**but how will i get the selected hobbies id...**
Please help

Answer (score 0):

maybe FormMethod.Post on your form?

and is your Model a class? 
Perhaps you could accept that in your post action then you'll find the id on it.

Answer (score 0):

without bothering with model binding, you can just add a FormCollection parameter to your POST method. That collection contains all form values posted.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(FormCollection collection)
{
  Hobby_Master hm = new Hobby_MasterService().GetHobby_Data(Hobby_Id);
  if (collection["Hobby_Id"] != null)
  {
   // collection["Hobby_Id"] contains the value selected in the dropdown box
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Show");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? I'd fire up the debugger and have a look at which values are posted to the method in the collection parameter. The key _should_ be "Hobby_Id" corresponding to the view code you posted, but i'd have a look in the debugger just to make sure.